# How to color cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

How do I color my negative data red and color my postive data green in Excel 2016? I have more than 300,000 data in 12 spreadsheets So I can't do it manually.

Comment: have you tried conditional formatting?

Comment: Need clarification whether you want to color the 'cell' (*highlight* or *fill*) or just the font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find yourself too limited by the option to use the "Format Cells" feature, there is also a feature called "Conditional Formatting". With this feature you can have styles applied to cells using arbitrary formulas.

As a starting point see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

Answer (score 1):

Use a number format that has red for negative values. There are some built-in already.

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it by a few secs but the positive numbers should be prefaced with **[color10]** or something similar. ([Number Format Code](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026BBD6-04BC-48CD-BF33-80F18B4EAE68)). Some people's computer show [color9] with a dark red better than [color3] for red.